# How to Create a Search Field in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-typescript

> I'm new to react-typescript, and I'm working on a project that uses a search bar to find data that I've gotten from my database.

I find the result in stackoverflow some one write the answer using React Js. But I want the answer in React-Typescript:
React Code below:

```
class BodyData extends React.Component {
  state = {
    query: "",
    data: [],
    filteredData: []
  };

  handleInputChange = event => {
    const query = event.target.value;

    this.setState(prevState => {
      const filteredData = prevState.data.filter(element => {
        return element.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase());
      });

      return {
        query,
        filteredData
      };
    });
  };

  getData = () => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:4000/restaurants`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const { query } = this.state;
        const filteredData = data.filter(element => {
          return element.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase());
        });

        this.setState({
          data,
          filteredData
        });
      });
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="searchForm">
        <form>
          <input
            placeholder="Search for..."
            value={this.state.query}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
        </form>
        <div>{this.state.filteredData.map(i => <p>{i.name}</p>)}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

> I want the sample autocomplete textbox code in React-Typescript
```

Comment: Is there a particular part of the types that you're having trouble with?

Comment: State Initialization part and this.setstate part.

Answer (score 0):

In typescript, React.Component is a generic. You can use that to define the types of your state and props. This will automatically apply the appropriate type definitions to both the state initialization and setState.

```
interface BodyDataProps {
  // if you have any props, put them here
}

interface BodyDataState {
  query: string;
  data: WhateverTheDataTypeIs[];
  filteredData: WhateverTheDataTypeIs[];
}

class BodyData extends React.Component<BodyDataProps, BodyDataState> {
  // rest of the class is the same
```

I don't know what your data looks like, so replace `WhateverTheDataTypeIs` with a type describing your data.